# How to change the Ignite to maintanance mode?

Tags: ignite

What is Ignite maintenance mode of Ignite, and how to change an ignite to this mode? I was stuck joining the node to the cluster and complains cleaning up the persistent data, however the data can be cleaned (using control.sh) only in the maintenance mode only.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special mode, similar to running Windows in a safe mode after a crash or a data corruption where most of the cluster functionality is disabled and a user is asked to perform some maintenance task to resolve the issue, most straightforward example I can think of is - to clean (remove) some corrupted files on disk just like in your question. You can refer to [IEP-53: Maintenance Mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-53%3A+Maintenance+Mode) proposal for the details.

I don't think that there is a way to enter this mode manually unless you trigger some preconfigured conditions like *stopping a node in the middle of checkpointing with WAL disabled*. Once the state is fixed, maintenance mode should be resolved automatically allowing a node to join the cluster.

Also, from my understanding, this mode is about a particular node rather than a complete cluster. I.e. you can have a 4-nodes cluster with only 1 node in maintenance mode, in that case, you have to run control.sh commands locally for the concrete failed node, not from another healthy node. If that's not the case, please provide more details or file a JIRA ticket because reported behavior looks quite broken to me.